# Application tried to present modally an active controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am getting the error:

```
Application tried to present modally an active controller
```

when I attempt to run my code below.

I am wanting to present a modal view-controller that is embedded within a `UINavigationController`. I have the `navigationVC` instantiated before this point. I only get this error when I run this code a second time. What I mean is that if I click a button and it runs this code it will work properly. I can than modally close that view. If I click the same button again to run it once more, I am getting  error.

```
- (void)pushToUserProfile
{
    if (!self.profileVC) {
        self.profileVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileVC"];
        [self.profileVC setCanEditProfile:NO];
        [self.profileVC setTitle:@"Profile"];
        [self.profileVC setCanCloseModal:YES];
    }

    [self.navigationVC setViewControllers:@[self.profileVC]];

    [self presentViewController:self.navigationVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What am I doing wrong below?:

edit:

I also run the code:

```
- (void)writeComment
{
    if (!self.writeCommentVC) {
        self.writeCommentVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"writeCommentVC"];
    }

    [self.navigationVC setViewControllers:@[self.writeCommentVC]];

    [self presentViewController:self.navigationVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and it works with no issue. Not matter how many times I present/dismiss that view controller.

Comment: Is `self` being shown from `self.navigationVC`?

Comment: @rmaddy self is not being shown from self.navigationVC. self has navigationVC under it. Also take a look at my edit.

Comment: Perhaps `self.profileVC` is already in view and you try to present it again.

Comment: Try [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.newController animated:YES completion:nil]; or [self presentViewController:self.newController animated:YES completion:nil]; - why are setting viewController via code - can't you manage visually in xcode it is less error prone

Comment: the code where self.navigationVC is beeing dismissed (writeCommentVC and profileVC) might be helpful.